# How to access the last folder in a directory?

Tags: command-line

My teacher made us unzip like 5 files one inside of another, until we arrived to this : `Trou/zxd/kuq/gsu/plm/secret`

How Can I read what is written in ‘’Secret’’ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If secret is a directory

```
ls Trou/zxd/kuq/gsu/plm/secret
```

from man ls

> NAME
>          ls - list directory contents
>
> SYNOPSIS
>          ls [OPTION]... [FILE]...
>
> DESCRIPTION
>          List information about the FILEs (the current directory by default).  Sort entries alphabetically if none of -cftuvSUX nor --sort
>   is specified.

If secret is a text file

```
cat  Trou/zxd/kuq/gsu/plm/secret
```